# Raise the log level of a library message in log4j2

Tags: java, log4j2

I have a library in my app that is logging everything at debug level. I cannot run my application with log level to set to debug for all or a subset of classes. This is  because the tool we use to collect logs from the machines ignores any messages logged below the INFO level. Is there a way to configure log4j2 to intercept the debug level messages and log them at info?

Comment: Why you can not run the application with some package in debug? At most the log collector will ignore those. Why do you need to do this?